# Starting another activity without pausing the previous one android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using Android 2.3. I am developing an application where I need to start a new activity, but I want my previous activity to be running. Basically, I am receiving ecg data via bluetooth and displaying it. Meanwhile I want to access some database for which I need to start a new activity. Is it possible to start this new activity without pausing the bluetooth data being received and displayed?

Answer (score 7):

Generally you cannot have two activities active at the same time (some vendor modifications support a 'multi-windows' mode of sorts though). You can use fragments and display/hide multiple sections in your UI. Anything that needs to keep running in the background you can run in a service, and then notify the UI about results you receive via callbacks, etc.